# How to use Week() in db2 with thursday as the starting day of the week instead on Monday or Sunday

Tags: db2

I am selecting some data grouped by week but I would like to select data from the table week wise with week starting with thursday.
I am currently working with Week(my_date) but it starts week with sunday and week_iso(my_date) starts the week with monday.
But I need to start the week from thursday.

Comment: Why with _Thursday_?  Is this to handle some sort of fiscal calendar - and if so, do you have a calendar table?  What happens with week 1/53 - Can the first week of the year start in December, or does it start with the first Thursday in January?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [date arithmetics](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html). Just add or subtract the difference of days to your start date.

```
week(my_date+4 days)
```

or

```
week_iso(my_date - 3 days)
```

The above are just examples. You need to adjust it depending on where you set your baseline, i.e., what is week 1.

Comment: The OP says that they're grouping on this information.  That's going to completely remove the possibility of using an index.  Plus, this might put things into the wrong "week" - OP might not be expecting week 1 to start in December.